# Launching a C# solution & project in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, monodevelop

When I first downloaded `MonoDevelop` on Mac and started learning, every time I loaded my `Solution`, it also opened my `Main.cs` and showed my code.

Recently, when I load my `Solution`, there is just a blank MonoDevelop screen, saying at the top that `Solution loaded..` and then I have to open my `Main.cs` through the `File` menu.

Have I done something to disable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Xamarin Studio. Last loaded files should be reopened after Xamarin Studio restart maybe there is bug(assuming you didn't close it) that doesn't do this...
There are many better ways to open project file then opening it via Open...

- Solution explorer pad(by default on right side of screen or open it via View->Pad->Solution) and there expand items to see your Main.cs
- Command+, will start search in top right corner where you can type Main and it will find your main file in solution

Comment: Thank you David. View->Pad->Solution is perfect.